# How to exclude / disable Redux devtools in production build or disconnect?

Tags: javascript, security, web, redux

As its name suggests devtools should be visible or accessible only during development and not in production. I don't want my end users playing with the state and dispatcher or seeing what's going on under the hood.

Is there a way to hide Redux Devtools or disconnect it in the production build?

I'm looking answers for Vanilla Redux. Not Redux Saga, Redux Thunk or Rematch.

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding the `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` enhancer in your `createStore` call? If you are, you can make adding that conditional.

Comment: IMO _nothing_ is truly private in client-side code anyway. The types of people that would try to dive into what's going on would be the same sorts that could reverse engineer what's going on as well, so it seems pointless to make big efforts to disable those tools.

Comment: Sorry guys, we were using old redux version. This question no longer applies to newer version.

Comment: Out of interest, being quite new to modern JS: is there a danger that something in your non production environments works by virtue of having devtools installed - perhaps including your manual test and automated test environments - and then something breaks in production as a result?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For someone using redux-toolkit

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    //your reducers
  },
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
```

Answer (score 32):

For hiding the Redux from devtools pay attention to the following code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import reducer from '~/redux/reducers';
import mySaga from '~/redux/sagas';
import { nodeEnv } from '~/utils/config';

const composeEnhancers =
  (nodeEnv !== 'production' &&
    typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default createStore(
  reducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga);
```

It is an integration between Redux and Redux-Saga that is not important the point is the:

```
const composeEnhancers =
  (nodeEnv !== 'production' &&
    typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;
```

The `composeEnhancers` is tuned just use `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` in the client and exactly development mode, otherwise the code just use `compose` and it means it will be hidden from browsers devtools.

Comment: I know it is not you @VijayPushkin, my answer for hiding from the redux extension is the right proper way, but for hiding from `ReactJS DevTools` is not possible. I try many ways but none of them couldn't hide a ReactJS project from extensions.

Comment: what does `nodeEnv` do?

Comment: suddenly getting something related: Uncaught ReferenceError: compose is not defined Help?
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb43f8aa1e38f1ee9aeb:712)
    at fn (bootstrap cb43f8aa1e38f1ee9aeb:117)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb43f8aa1e38f1ee9aeb:712)
    at fn (bootstrap cb43f8aa1e38f1ee9aeb:117)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:100671)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cb43f8aa1e38f1ee9aeb:712)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap cb43f8aa1e38f1ee9aeb:25)
    at app.bundle.js:1

Answer (score 31):

These guys didn't really give the required answer but i found it out my self on the redux documentation for vanilla redux,
if you pass the `devTools: true` in your store.js then it will work in both production and development but you can disable it in this way :

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';
import chatReducer from '../features/chatSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    chat: chatReducer,
  },
  devTools: false,
});
```

The above code is of the store.js

This worked for me as i was also working with vanilla redux when you are doing developments just make the `devTools: true` and run your app it will work

**NOTE :** As said by @JamesPlayer in comment ([link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909402/how-to-exclude-disable-redux-devtools-in-production-build-or-disconnect/64745088?noredirect=1#comment116882757_64745088)), this solution will work if you are using `@reduxjs/toolkit`

Comment: It should be mentioned that this only works if you're using the [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)

Comment: `devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',` for development only

Answer (score 12):

if you use `redux-devtools-extension`, you can configure your store easily this way :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  // options like actionSanitizer, stateSanitizer
});
const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

The logger in the dev tools will be disabled in production. Instead of `developmentOnly`, you can add `logOnlyInProduction` to see the logs in production.

Comment: official source: the last line [of this point](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#14-using-in-production) in the github page

Comment: You didn't answer the question at all

Answer (score 4):

Though I later found out that this question is longer valid for new versions of Redux, some readers were unaware of it, since nobody has pointed this out and everyone here was talking about excluding `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` from compose enhancers during Redux Saga setup.

What I found out was there are few different **Redux Devtools**

### 1. [reduxjs/redux-devtools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools)

This one is from the official repo by [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov)

[`reduxjs/redux-devtools`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) is the NPM package which you want to add in your enhancers to use Redux Devtools in your project.

For Manual integration and exclusion in production checkout this [page](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/blob/master/docs/Walkthrough.md#manual-integration).

### 2. [zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)

From the previous answers and comments to my old boilerplate code, this was the one used by all of them.

You add this devtools by `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` to your enhancers.

```js
 const store = createStore(
   reducer, /* preloadedState, */
   development() && 
     window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
 );
```

and in production it should be removed.

### 3. [infinitered/reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron)

Reactotron is a macOS, Windows, and Linux app for inspecting your React JS and React Native apps built on Electron. This one is sweet. It is a cross-platform Electron app for inspecting React and React Native apps, including app state, API requests, perf, errors, sagas, and action dispatching.

You just plug it as your dev-dependency, so it will add nothing to the production build.

---

For the ones using Redux with [Rematch](https://github.com/rematch/rematch), it's a different story.

### Redux With Rematch

Rematch works with Redux Devtools out of the box. No configuration required.

```js
init() // initialized with devtools
```

For manual integration,

```js
init({
    redux: {
        devtoolOptions: {
            disabled: production(),
        },
    },
})
```

You can also make rematch use `redux-devtools-extension` or `reactotron`. Checkout this [page](https://rematch.github.io/rematch/#/recipes/devtools.md) for more info.

Comment: The best way to do this is not to "remove that code" in production. You don't want to have to remember to remove code before deploying. The best solution is to detect whether you are in a production environment and to not enable dev tools in that case.

Comment: That goes without saying, doesn't it? @Cully

Comment: You gave an example of how to include dev tools and then said, "and in production you remove that code."

Comment: Updated my answer with env conditionals

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following line to your `index.js` file

```
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    : null || compose;
```

Answer (score 2):

as from the [official documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-devtools-extension) :

> There’re just [few lines of code](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/npm-package/index.js). If you don’t want to allow the
> extension in production, just use
> ‘redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly’ instead of
> ‘redux-devtools-extension’.

Answer (score 1):

simple import the **composeWithDevTools** from redux-devtools-extension and end users won't see the devtool extension in production..

```
import {composeWithDevTools} from "redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly";
```

Answer (score 0):

easy way to disable production logs is exist,

```
let middleware = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? [sagaMiddleware, logger] : [sagaMiddleware];
```

and done!